# Exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass

Tags: java, classcastexception, objectinputstream

I made an application which can securely transfer files between systems...
All works fine... except at receiving end. it shows an

```
Exception in thread "New Connection" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at network.FileDownload.secureFileReceive(FileDownload.java:341)
at network.FileDownload.run(FileDownload.java:240)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The client side program's(FileDownload) line at which the exception occurs is

```
String bb = security.decrypt((int[][]) input1.readObject());
byte[] buf = bb.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

The server side of lines are

```
output1.writeObject( security.encrypt(new String(buf,"ISO-8859-1")));
```

Here, the security class has methods for encrytion n decryption where `security.encrypt()` takes String and returns int[][]. `security.decrypt` does vice-versa.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the type of the `output1` object?

Comment: its ObjectOutputStream

Comment: Why are you casting it into int[][] ? Can't you staright away call something like output1.writeObject(( security.encrypt(new String(buf,"ISO-8859-1"))); ?

Comment: sry for that....i have just added that..... and without that too the error occurs

Answer (score 2):

Seams to me, that at the server side `writeObject`, transforms your `int[][]` cast to some kind of `object` so that it can send, then of course you can´t cast an object at the client side with (`int[][]`) the system doesn't know how to do that ...

i hope that is clear, what you need is an object serializer at both sides.

Good luck ...

Comment: ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream do the same

Comment: maybe try with Integer instead of int, since Integer is not a native type. And also instead of cast, do like new Integer(object) hope it helps

Comment: dude that'll create an Integer object and not an int value.... which is expected by security.decrypt()

Comment: forgive me for my ignorance, but after you transported andInteger object, you can return an int value ... the whole problem it seams is that you are passing a primative type object. but i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have sending from server through the body. That body contain invalid characters. That is the reason your getting cast exaction.I have stuck same issues in day then i solved it changing the message body.